# PHP: Better way to filter out duplicates?

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, unique

I have an array sort of like this.

```
$images = array
(
    array('src' => 'a.jpg'),
    array('src' => 'b.jpg'),
    array('src' => 'c.jpg'),
    array('src' => 'd.jpg'),
    array('src' => 'b.jpg'),
    array('src' => 'c.jpg'),
    array('src' => 'b.jpg'),
);
```

There is also height and width, but not important here. What I want is to remove the duplicates. What I have done feels rather clunky.

```
$filtered = array();
foreach($images as $image)
{
    $filtered[$image['src']] = $image;
}
$images = array_values($filtered);
```

Is there a better way to do this? Any advice?

Comment: Can't think of one, only thing I'd probably do is change your central line to `if(isset($filtered[$image['src']])) $filtered[$image['src']] = $image;
`

Comment: This seems to be a good solution that runs in linear time.

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be a good use case for [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

```
$images = array_values(array_reduce($images, function($acc, $curr){
    $acc[$curr['src']] = $curr;
    return $acc;
}, array()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

```
$images = array_unique($images);
```

Comment: does that work for arrays? would it check all the array keys and values?

Comment: Note: This will work in this particular instance because the array key is the same (`src`). However, this is not a solution if the array keys were different but contained the same value as `array_unique` only compares values. RTFM.

Comment: -1 Read the note to `array_unique`: “Two elements are considered equal if and only if `(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2`. In words: when the string representation is the same.”

Answer (score 0):

How are you building the array?  Possibly keep it from ever being added using...

```
if(!in_array($needle, $haystackarray)){
    AddToArray;
}
```

Just a thought.

Comment: I just like to use this since for me at least it's very self descriptive of whats happening and from what I'm looking at should allow you to solve your problem in a single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use

```
$filtered = array_flip(array_flip($images))
```

You have to understand [array_flip's](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) behavior though or you might get unexpected results. Some things to note are:

1. This will remove duplicate values
2. It removes NULL values
3. It preserves keys, however, it retains the **last** duplicate value (not the first)
4. A function would need to be written to handle multidimensional arrays

Answer (score -1):

Use PHP's [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

**Code:**

```
$filtered = array_unique($images);
```

Comment: -1 Read the note to `array_unique`: “Two elements are considered equal if and only if `(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2`. In words: when the string representation is the same.”